# How to achieve this A-Zindex navigation in my vue + elementUI project?

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GQJd.png)
As the picture shows,I wanna know how to do this alphabetically-ordered navigation,never do it before, now don't know how to do it, who can help me? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: <el-autocomplete
            v-model="filters.search"
            class="w-100"
            :fetch-suggestions="querySearchAsync"
            prefix-icon="el-icon-search"
  
            placeholder="search"
            @select="handleSerach">
          </el-autocomplete>

Comment: <el-select v-model="value" placeholder="pls select" class="w-100" @change="handleSelect($event)">
          <!--<span>filter</span>-->
          <!--<span v-for="(letter,index) in letters" :key='index'>{{letter}} </span>-->
          <el-option
            v-for="item in products"
            :key="item.price"
            :label="item.name"
            :value="item.label">
          </el-option>
        </el-select>